# OpenVPN2 server, use TLS for handshake but only require username/password for auth

Tags: debian, ssl, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup `OpenVPN2` `server` for only requiring username and password for authentication, but still use `TLS` for encryption on handshake etc., but not require `client` `certificate`.

Is that possible with ``` OpenVPN2``server ```?

This is my `server.conf`:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /home/my_server/ca.crt
cert /home/my_server/cert.pem
key /home/my_server/key.pem

dh /home/my_server/dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

cipher AES-256-CBC

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

I'm going to look at https://openvpn.net/community-resources/using-alternative-authentication-methods/ for `username` and `password`, but I'm unable to find anything for not requiring `client` `certificate`?

Comment: You could use `client-cert-not-required`, probably in conjunction with `username-as-common-name` (it's right there on your linked page...) and `tls-auth` with a PSK.

Comment: Thank you, will you make answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip certificate authentication using `client-cert-not-required` and `username-as-common-name` in the configuration. Best to use `tls-auth` with a preshared key between client and server, too.